# pymodbus read_file_record operation does not seem to work

Tags: modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

I'm trying to test read file functionality of python pymodbus client library. However, after a write operation, a read operation to exact address returns empty fields:

```py
async def test_file_record(client):
    records = [
        FileRecord(
            record_data=b"\x00\x01\x02\x03",
            reference_type = 0x06, file_number = 0x01, record_number = 0x01, record_length = 0x02
        ),
    ]
    resp = await client.write_file_record(records, slave=SLAVE)
    if resp.isError():
        raise Exception(f"ERROR: modbus returned an error: {resp}")
    print(resp.__dict__)

    resp = await client.read_file_record([
        FileRecord(
            reference_type = 0x06, file_number = 0x01, record_number = 0x01, record_length = 0x02
        ),
    ], slave=SLAVE)
    if resp.isError():
        raise Exception(f"ERROR: modbus returned an error: {resp}")
    print(resp.__dict__)
```

```bash
{'transaction_id': 1, 'protocol_id': 0, 'slave_id': 1, 'skip_encode': False, 'check': 0, 'bits': [], 'registers': [], 'records': [FileRecord(file=1, record=1, length=2)]}
{'transaction_id': 2, 'protocol_id': 0, 'slave_id': 1, 'skip_encode': False, 'check': 0, 'bits': [], 'registers': [], 'records': []}
```

When I reviewed the library code, strangely it just uses empty list to create a response:

from file_message.py file:

```py
    def execute(self, _context):
        """Run a read exception status request against the store.

        :returns: The populated response
        """
        # TODO do some new context operation here # pylint: disable=fixme
        # if file number, record number, or address + length
        # is too big, return an error.
        files = []
        return ReadFileRecordResponse(files)
```